# Using OpenGL on top of a MKMapView?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, mapkit

I've got some data that I would like to render on top of a MKMapView using OpenGL. Currently I can sort of achieve this by placing a transparent OpenGL layer on top of the MKMapView and drawing to it using OpenGL commands.

However, the problem becomes synching the drawing of the OpenGL layer with the drawing that MKMapView does. I can kind of get around this by drawing on touch events, this works well until you "flick" the map which causes a continuous series of draws for the animation that I don't detect.

Another idea was to use a MKOverlayView and hope that OpenGL drawing could be done with it. But I'm not sure how exactly to app

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend evaluating [BA3's "Altus" mapping engine](http://www.ba3.us/?page=pages/mapping-engine). It is built entirely in OpenGL, so in the worst case you may simple render to the same context. However, it would probably be better if you could take advantage of their support for geo-located raster, vector and marker elements.

Full disclosure: I'm friends with the authors, but have no financial interest.